# educode Unexpected token else

Tags: javascript

I am working on a Codecademy lesson on if/else statements and I repeatedly get an error saying, "Unexpected token else". Please help. Here is the code:

```
var year = prompt("Enter a year (ex: 2000)");
year = Number(year);

console.log("The year " + year + " is...");

var isDividableBy4 = isDividableBy(year, 4);

if (isDividableBy4 == true) {
  var isDividableBy100 = isDividableBy(year, 100);

  if (isDividableBy100 == true) {
    var isDividableBy400 = isDividableBy(year, 400);
  }
  if (isDividableBy400 == true) {
    console.log("a leap year")
  } else {
    console.log("not a leap year")
  } else {
    console.log("a leap year")
  }
} else {
  console.log("not a leap year");
}
```

Comment: You can't have two "else" statements for a single "if". You may have left out a nesting level.

Comment: After your `if(isDividableBy400 == true)` condition you have 2 `else` clauses.

Comment: [You are allowed _one_ `else` in an `if...else` statement.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else)

Comment: @MohammadShamsKhan Revise your logic so that there aren't two consecutive `else` blocks. When do you expect the second `else` to be entered?

Comment: Replace the fourth question mark with an else statement for the if statement created in the third step. Inside the code block of this else statement, use a console.log() instruction to display the message "not a leap year".
Replace the fifth question mark with an else statement for the if statement created in the first step. Inside the code block of this else statement, use a console.log() instruction to display the message "a leap year".

Comment: Isn't that what you're being asked to figure out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code contains 2 `else`s for a single if.

I guess that your algorithm should look like:

```js
var year = prompt("Enter a year (ex: 2000)");
year = Number(year);

console.log("The year " + year + " is...");

var isDividableBy4 = isDividableBy(year, 4);

if (isDividableBy4 == true) {
    var isDividableBy100 = isDividableBy(year, 100);

    if (isDividableBy100 == true) {
        var isDividableBy400 = isDividableBy(year, 400);
          // <-- The parenthese previously here was misplaced
        if (isDividableBy400 == true) {
            console.log("a leap year")
        } else {
            console.log("not a leap year")
        } // <- I moved it here
    } else {
        console.log("a leap year")
    }
} else {
    console.log("not a leap year");
}
```

Formatting code correctly helps spot such mistakes.

Comment: Thanks for helping

Comment: @MohammadShamsKhan If this solves your question you can mark my answer as "accepted" by ticking the check mark on the left.